# TemplateDoesNotExist for detail.html but works for index.html (Django Tutorial Part 3)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to fix this strange error where one template works perfectly fine but the other doesn't. I'm following the Django tutorial and when it comes to the part where I'm supposed to raise a 404 error the prompt tells me that detail.html does not exist at the given source even though it *does*.

My `views.py` file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import Http404

from .models import Question

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index1.html', context)

def detail(request, question_id):
    question = Question.objects.get(pk = question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})
```

the error:

```
Internal Server Error: /polls/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\env\Scripts\mysite\polls\views.py", line 15, in detail
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: polls/detail.html
```

The following is what shows up on the webpage:

```
Template-loader postmortem
    Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
    
    Using engine django:
    
    django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\env\Scripts\mysite\polls\templates\polls\detail.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Admin\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\env\Scripts\mysite\polls\templates\polls\detail.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Admin\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\polls\detail.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Admin\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\polls\detail.html (Source does not exist)
```

But look: `detail.html` does exist at the location along with `index.html`! I've checked at least 30 times, `index.html` is being called (at `/polls/`) but the other isn't; *why*?

Location of the detail.html file:

C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\env\Scripts\mysite\polls\templates\polls

My Project Directory is given as:

```
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 0EBA-8389
C:.
|   db.sqlite3
|   manage.py
|   tree.txt
|   
+---mysite
|   |   asgi.py
|   |   settings.py
|   |   urls.py
|   |   wsgi.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   
|   \---__pycache__
|           settings.cpython-38.pyc
|           urls.cpython-38.pyc
|           wsgi.cpython-38.pyc
|           __init__.cpython-38.pyc
|           
\---polls
    |   admin.py
    |   apps.py
    |   models.py
    |   tests.py
    |   urls.py
    |   views.py
    |   __init__.py
    |   
    +---migrations
    |   |   0001_initial.py
    |   |   __init__.py
    |   |   
    |   \---__pycache__
    |           0001_initial.cpython-38.pyc
    |           __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    |           
    +---templates
    |   \---polls
    |           detail.html.txt
    |           ffs.html.txt
    |           index.html.txt
    |           index1.html
    |           
    \---__pycache__
            admin.cpython-38.pyc
            apps.cpython-38.pyc
            models.cpython-38.pyc
            urls.cpython-38.pyc
            views.cpython-38.pyc
            __init__.cpython-38.pyc
```

I've tried looked at every single question of a similar nature on S/O but nothing is helping, most of the answers are asking for `settings.py` to be changed and I really did not want to because I shouldn't have to at this early of a stage, but I still ended up hard-coding the template's path in `TEMPLATES_DIRS` (didn't work even though for everyone else it somehow does):

```
    """
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '(ovz73&%u#!99!#m_$s1q0j6a&ojdpe=1@1&fr)u84v*=j457g'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [r'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\env\Scripts\mysite\polls\templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

There is some other import os stuff that I tried, and honestly, not only is it not working, it's going over my head (I started learning Django less than 3 days ago).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a few things:

Can you share your settings.py file?

Can you show your project directory structure?

Can you try changing TEMPLATES in settings.py to this?

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: hey, thanks for responding. i haven't yet tried changing Templates to what you asked me to, but I have edited the question to include the entirety of settings.py as well as the Project Directory. I just noticed that the detail.html file is saved as detail.txt.html instead  as shown in the directory; could this be the issue, and if so, how would I resolve it?

Comment: i meant detail.html.txt*

Comment: absoultely - you need to remove the .txt suffix

Comment: but being a text file it's getting saved as .txt by default, i'm unable to alter that

Comment: You should certainly be able to edit the file name/extension. - Nevertheless, you can change your the template name string like so in your views function: `return render(request, 'polls/detail.html.txt', context)`